# How to enable federated engine in docker mariadb

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, mariadb

I need the `federated engine` in the entrypoint for pre populate database in the container. To enable the `federated engine` I wrote a bash script to manual insert the federated command to the my.cnf, but getting error below

> 2021-07-20 16:14:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/_enable_federated.sh
> sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/mysql/sedHjVLxp: Permission denied

**_enable_federated.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sed -i '/\[mysqld\]/a federated' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

May I know what is the correct way to enable `federated engine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to install the federated storage engine is to run the container with the command line argument  `--plugin-load-add=ha_federatedx`

Alternately for a configuration file based approach use the (ref: "Using a custom MariaDB configuration file" in [documenation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb)):

```
$ cat config/federated.cnf

[mariadbd]
plugin-load-add=ha_federated

$ podman run -v=./config/:/etc/mysql/conf.d/ -e MARIADB_ALLOW_ROOT_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1  mariadb:10.5
```

The final way is to use in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` a `federated.sql` script:

```
INSTALL SONAME 'ha_federatedx';
```

Comment: I tried the command argument option. It works !!! 
TQVM